# Removing Console.log label for karma spec reporter

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, console.log

I want to remove the `LOG LOG` label for the console.log() messages with karam spec runner.

```
LOG LOG: '√ Form Scenario 1: All values'
```

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I removed my answer, because I thought you wanted to hide the logs altogether. My answer had the following solution: add `client: { captureConsole: false }` to the karma.conf.js file. Now I understand, you want to hide the *LOG LOG* prefix which I can not give you a solution for.

Comment: @VadiemJanssens Anyway thanks :)